# Ruby on Rails - How to know how many time the same Object appears in Array using Active Record?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

How to know how many times the same Object appears in Array?
I want to check how many times I found the object, like:

```
array = ['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','D']
```

So, A appeared three times, B twice, C three too, and only one for D.

I know that if I use "find_all", like:

```
array.find_all{ |e| array.count(e) > 1 }
```

I will get with answer

```
["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"]
```

but, how I can count this? I want something like:

```
 A = 3, B = 2, C = 3, D = 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inject on the array to iterate over the array and pass a hash into each iteration to store data. So to retrieve the count of the array you gave you would do this:

```
array = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"]
array.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |hash, array_item| 
  hash[array_item] += 1
  hash # this will be passed into the next iteration as the hash parameter
end

=> {"A"=>3, "B"=>2, "C"=>3}
```

Passing in `Hash.new(0)` rather than `{}` will mean that the default value for each key when you first encounter it will be 0.